# Complex exponential proof

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that if $z$ = $r^{i\theta}$, then $z^i = e^{-\theta} [\cos(\ln r) + i \sin(\ln r)]$. Developing the LHS, I obtain $e^{-\theta \ln(r)}$. Developing the RHS, I get $e^{-\theta + i \ln(r)}$. Any tips on how to obtain this proof?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

EDIT: There was a typo. $z$ should be taken as $re^{i \theta}$.

Comment: Usually in polar form, one might let $z=re^{i\theta}$ instead. Does your question have a typo?

Comment: I feel there is a typo in the question as well, because if we put $r=1$, we get $z=1$ from the first equation, but $z=e^{i \theta}$ from the second.

Comment: ($1.$) What is $z$ (A complex number of any magnitude ($|z|$)? A complex number on the unit circle ($|z|=1$)? ...) The same questions arise for $r$ and $\theta$ as well, so please provide a little more information. ($2.$) Also, it would be nice if you state your motivation behind the question and want the title to be a bit clearer, as that way the title could be used for all questions about proofs with complex exponentials, so that the question meets the Math.SE standards.

Comment: @KevinDietrich I'm going to push back on the terminology, as $z, r, \theta$ are standard for complex numbers, and once you provide the context that it is about complex numbers, their interpretation should be obvious to people familiar in complex number analysis (though explicit explanations of notation are always welcome). However, I agree that a less vague title more specific to the question at hand and some motivation would make the post nicer.

Comment: There was a typo finally in the question, thank you for pointing it out! I developed the RHS and obtained the LHS with $z = re^{i \theta}$. As I am a new contributor, I am not familiar with the Math.SE standards and will provide a clearer title and better state the motivation in the future! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Define $z^{i}$.

Comment: You should actually just fix the question. Only writing edit at the bottom will still confuse anyone who just skims the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is typo in the question. Correct seems to be: $z = r \space e^{i\theta} = e^{i\theta +\space ln(r)}$.

In that case $z^{i} = e^{-\theta \space + i\space ln(r)} = e^{-\theta}[\cos(ln(r)) + i \space \sin(ln(r))]$

Note that you have to be careful, because adding (a multiple of) $2\pi$ to $\theta$ does not affect $z$, but does change the value of $z^{i}$. So you have to be precise about what you want to do.

Comment: $(a^{b})^{c}=a^{bc}$ is not valid for complex numbers. In fact, $z^{i}$ does not have a unique value.

Comment: Yes, that is true. One has to be careful. $\theta$ has a period of $2\pi$, so you must select a branch before you can do exponentiation.

Answer (score -1):

This is false. Note that increasing $\theta$ by $2\pi$ doesn’t affect $z$ nor $z^i$ but does affect the other side. You need to add some clarification on what’s a given and how things are defined.